# Media query styles not retained when applied through chrome dev tools

Tags: media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

I have been having issues as regards to styles applied to the html element, these changes were made through the chrome dev tools. I made sure my text editor and the chrome dev tool's editor were synchronized so that any changes made in the dev tool appears in my editor. The problem is when I make changes to my lines code, the changes goes away once I refresh my browser even though I saved the changes made and it reflects in my local text editor. What could I be doing wrong please, I have searched online for answers but nothing.**Please bear with me if the question is too long but I wanted to be as detailed as possible.**
**P.S: I applied this changes using media queries because I achieve better results that way.** [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN8zl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, all you need to do is make the desired media queries from your text editor and not from chrome dev tool and it will be solved.

NB: Chrome Dev tools are more for you to preview your work and not for permanent changes, that is why when you refresh the page everything will be gone.

You should try using !important on your styles.
eg

```
.media{
@media only screen and (max-width:568px){
width:100% !important;}}
```

I use this all times when i meet this kind of issue

Comment: I did that already and here is how, after making the changes in the chrome dev tools I copy the code from the inline style for the selected element then paste it into my local editor, but still the changes do not stick.